# How to reload ajax url after post to php?

Tags: php, ajax, web, reload

Here, I use ajax post some data to my PHP file, how to `reload the URL(PHP`) under the success function?
`window.location.reload();` doesn't work.

```
function saveChanges(arr){
                       $.ajax({
                        data: { rowdata:arr, editingid:rowId },
                        url: '../app/course.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        success: function(){
                            //reload url here

                        }
                    });

                    }//end of saveChanges()
```

Comment: maybe you are getting error from ajax request add error callback inside the ajax and check it if you are receiving errors or not;

Comment: use window.location.href = url;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.reload();` after ajax success.

```
function saveChanges(arr){
    $.ajax({
       data: { rowdata:arr, editingid:rowId },
       url: '../app/course.php',
       method: 'POST',
       success: function(){
          location.reload();
       }
   });

}//end of saveChanges()
```

Comment: But this saveChanges function is in a different php file, not course.php..
I want to reload another php in this function

Answer (score 0):

```
location.reload();
```

Moreover, you may check it out [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) from here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways where you can use to redirect/refresh the page.

1. You can simply use the JavaScript `location.reload()` method to refresh or reloads the page. This method optionally accepts a Boolean parameter true or false. If the parameter true is specified, it causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. However, if it is false (which is default) or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.
2. You can also use `window.location.href = "https://www.url.com/";` where you can redirect it to specific page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (Not Tested).

```
function saveChanges(arr){
var url = window.location.href; 
    $.ajax({
       data: { rowdata:arr, editingid:rowId },
       url: '../app/course.php',
       method: 'POST',
       success: function(success){
         if(success){
           // do something here
             window.location.href = url; // reload the page
          }
       }
   });

}//end of saveChanges()
```

if you want to add some parameters in URL you can add it before reloading the page as:

```
url +='?param1=1&param2=2'
```